# Upload multiple files to S3 from stdin

Tags: command-line, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I found the option to upload to S3 from stdin:

```
cat test.txt | aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/test.text
```

But I have a tgz archive coming in via curl and containing multiple files. I want to write the contents into an S3 bucket. This is what I would like to do:

```
curl http://rapidsai-data.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/notebook-mortgage-data/mortgage_2000.tgz | tar xvz - | aws s3 sync - s3://mybucket/
```

However sync does not support stream input and cp does not support multiple files. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the CLI supports multiple files from stdin by design.

Sync explicitly deals with one local directory and one S3 bucket - no mention of stdin support in docs. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Copy works with a single local file and single remote S3 key and as you describe will accept input from stdin. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

As i see it you can either extract the files locally and use `s3 sync` (or extract the files and run a script to iterate each file and use `s3 cp` on each file).

If your tight on space you might consider uploading the TGZ via stdin to some temporary location in S3 then using a separate process to download, extract and upload the individual files - but theres no getting round the need to extract the files then upload AFAIK.

Comment: Thx... but I wouldn't bother if that were an option. The data to be transferred is a bit too big for that. I think so who created the data source should have thought about that.